# Apache(httpd) virtual host configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I am trying to configure virtual host on local web server
What i want is when i go to localhost or server IP i want to see the default centos page and when i go to the other websites that are configured in /etc/hosts then i want to see those websites.

Is this the correct configuration for this setup? Its not working as i want..because now all websites go to default centos page which is not what i want.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@web1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@web1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost/web1.com/html/
    ServerName web1.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/vhost/web1.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/vhost/web1.com/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@web2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost/web2.com/html/
    ServerName web2.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/vhost/web2.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/vhost/web2.com/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is correct. Two things - restart apache and clear browser cache before refreshing one of your configured sites

Comment: @Krzysztof Księżyk yes it worked seconds after posting this question..but here is another question i have my /etc/hosts has `192.168.1.5 web1.com, www.web1.com`  `192.168.1.5 web2.com, www.web2.com` to be able to run the websites in local network but i noticed even though in my virtual host configuration i had we1.com and we2.com as the ServerNames why is www.web1.com and www.web2.com but the web1.com and web2.com not working in browser?

Comment: @redhatengineer6 you should update the question, you are now asking a different question and you shouldn't do it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your virtual host just below ServerName web1.com:

```
ServerAlias *.web1.com
```

This is an answer to the comment in your question, you should edit the question to put that question in it.

Comment: i am not sure you read the question/comment well...i put web1.com but then browser recognized www.web1.com and does not web1.com

Answer (score -2):

If you're configuring Apache in Ubuntu server, go to the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file and add below lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@web1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost/web1.com/html/
    ServerName web1.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/vhost/web1.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/vhost/web1.com/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@web2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost/web2.com/html/
    ServerName web2.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/vhost/web2.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/vhost/web2.com/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

And add the below lines in host file (`/etc/hosts`) as well:

```
127.0.1.1    web1.com
127.0.1.2    web2.com
```

Comment: isn't this what OP wrote above?

Comment: host entries were missing

Comment: NameVirtualHost is missing too, which is the most important piece in this context...